# Response code: 400 Response message: Bad Request Apache jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to send post request to the following body data:

```
 {
  "messageId": "covisintAutomatedTest",

  "deviceId": "5a1d5f0f-8c3e-4524-990c-839385e1317c",
  "eventTemplateId": "0494a7ce-5786-45f5-a1d5-e61ce553165f",
  "velocity": 44.5
}
```

and header details:

```
  'accept: application/json' 
  'authorization: Bearer 2|uZDQS2AQNF6725SN4L5AmGHnidf9' 
  'cache-control: no-cache' 
  'content-type: application/json'
  'postman-token: fdffe55a-8f0f-3dc9-c714-3533df9a3025'
```

the structure is as follows:

```
Test Plan
Thread
Http Header Manager
View Results Tree
```

it is showing error 400. could you please guide me why and how do i fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

There's nothing with your plan structure or whatever else in JMeter, it's a SERVER'S response, and the problem is - you don't even understand that fact.

So please, give yourself and everyone around you a favour: learn the basics of what you're working with.

Answer (score 6):

I had a billy-o of a time debugging something like this, JMeter was reporting:

```
<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: Header Folding</pre>
```

But I turned on a bunch of logging in my Spring application and couldn't see anything in the logs.

In the end this turned out to be caused by having a blank row in the `HTTP Header Manager` that I was using for authentication and other header stuff.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the request body is correct
make sure that there are no missing headers : one way to do that is to perform the same request using postman, if it was successful check the headers that was generated by postman and add the missing ones in your jmeter.
if the request is not successful on postman check the server itself (logs if you are logging "you should")